# Resizing image inside of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have been trying to get the system images I placed inside of a UIButton to scale aspect fit, but no solutions I find online seem to work. This is what I have tried so far:

```
//the cells objects
var acceptButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
var declineButton = UIButton(type: .custom)


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    //add the contents and set its autolayout constraints
    setAutoLayoutConstraints()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

//function to set the autolayout constraints for the cell's contents
func setAutoLayoutConstraints() {
    
    //create the stack view which will contain the accept and reject buttons
    let buttonStackView = UIStackView()
    buttonStackView.axis = .horizontal
    buttonStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    buttonStackView.alignment = .fill
    
    //add the buttons to the stack view
    buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(acceptButton)
    buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(declineButton)
    
    //add the button stack view to the cell
    self.addSubview(buttonStackView)
    buttonStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    //add the button images
    let addImage = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    acceptButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    acceptButton.setImage(addImage, for: .normal)
    acceptButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    acceptButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    let declineImage = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
    declineButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    declineButton.setImage(declineImage, for: .normal)
    declineButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(declineButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    
                    
}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

(The "test test" label is just what I added for the left half of the cell's contents, can be ignored)

I have tried multiple solutions such as setting the edge insets, setting the content mode of the button and the button's image view, using a custom button, etc. but I can't seem to get the image to resized.

NOTE: When I make the image the background image with setBackgroundImage, I am able to resize the button but I can not scale aspect fit it, only fill it horizontally and vertically which is not what I am looking to do.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution example: add first your labelTest and after that set stackView leading anchor to labelTest trailing...
this is my tableView:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


let tableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .green
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    tableView.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    
    return cell
 }
}
```

Now set my cell with arrangedSubviews and set constraints to content view (this is the correct way, not directly to cell):

```
class myCell: UITableViewCell {

let labelTest: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "test Label"
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()

var acceptButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
var declineButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    acceptButton.backgroundColor = .purple
    declineButton.backgroundColor = .brown
    setAutoLayoutConstraints()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

//function to set the autolayout constraints for the cell's contents
func setAutoLayoutConstraints() {
    
    contentView.addSubview(labelTest)
    labelTest.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    labelTest.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    labelTest.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    labelTest.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let buttonStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [acceptButton, declineButton])
    buttonStackView.axis = .horizontal
    buttonStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    buttonStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    //add the button stack view to the cell
    contentView.addSubview(buttonStackView)
    buttonStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelTest.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    //add the buttons images
    let addImage = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    acceptButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    acceptButton.setImage(addImage, for: .normal)
    acceptButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    acceptButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    let declineImage = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
    declineButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    declineButton.setImage(declineImage, for: .normal)
    declineButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(declineButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)               
 }
}
```

If you want some space to left/right simply add constant to relative constraint:

```
labelTest.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
buttonStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

This is the results

[image]
[image]